# Error in R "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" despite using $ on the code

Tags: r, operator-keyword

I used Spotify API to extract data about BTS.

```
library(Rspotify)
library(spotifyr)
library(magrittr)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(httpuv)

options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)

app_id <- "xxx"
app_secret <- "xxx"
token <- "1"

keys <- spotifyOAuth(token, app_id, app_secret)
find_my_artist <- searchArtist("BTS", token = keys)
View(find_my_artist)
```

I didn't use any $ operators nor atomic values, but the below error message keep coming up.
I want to know where the error is coming from and how to fix it.
(app_id and app_secret, I replaced "XXX" with my own credentials)

```
> find_my_artist <- searchArtist("BTS", token = keys)
Error in json1$artists : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

Comment: Type `searchArtist` to see the code for that function.  It looks as though the error happened on the 3rd line of that function.  Something went wrong, and it didn't check that it had received data in the right format.